# Возврат текста с onclick

Tags: javascript

Как зафигачить, чтобы спойлер умел закрываться.

html:

```
<a href="" id='666' class="spoiler_links" onclick="changeText();">Спойлер [+]</a>
```

js:

```
function changeText(){
 document.getElementById('666').innerHTML = 'Спойлер [-]'; 
}
```

Comment: зафигачить не получится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как то так. код кривой немного, зато рабочий)) http://jsfiddle.net/ptHqy/

Answer (score 2):

Или так

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText()
{
    var obj = document.getElementById('number666'),
        txt = obj.innerHTML;

    if (/\+/.test(txt))
      obj.innerHTML = txt.replace('+','-');
    else
      obj.innerHTML = txt.replace('-','+');
}
</script>

<a href="" id="number666" class="spoiler_links" onclick="changeText(); return false;">Спойлер [+]</a>
```

Comment: @Aaron, хорошее решение, плюсую